# Returning the last data's id on MySql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table, in this table I have 10 rows, in these 10 rows I only want to return the data 1-5 and get the last result id.

I have tried

```sql
SELECT id FROM my_list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

but this gives me the result 10-6 instead of 5-1.

Comment: How about `LIMIT 5,5`?

Comment: with `1-5` do you mean rows or ids? if rows passerby solution should work

Comment: so try passerby solution, this will give  you five rows starting from row `5`

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT id FROM my_list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5
```

?

Comment: This will give result in ascending order from 1-5, but op wants data in descending  order 5-1.

Comment: Yes, as Yogesh stated I needed it to be DESC to print out the first result using mysql_fetch_assoc_firstrow_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_firstrow_id);
  $last_id = $mysql_fetch_assoc_firstrow_id['id'];

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id FROM my_list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5
) temp ORDER BY temp.id DESC
```

Comment: I needed it to be DESC to print out the first result using mysql_fetch_assoc_firstrow_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_firstrow_id);
  $last_id = $mysql_fetch_assoc_firstrow_id['id'];

Comment: @kuwame Yes, my query will give you result in descending order 5-1.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you need fifth record from table then you can use this

select * from my_list ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT 5,1

Answer (score 0):

Give LIMIT

```
SELECT id FROM my_list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6,5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM my_list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6,5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `table_name`.`id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 4
```

Comment: I needed it to be DESC to print out the first result using mysql_fetch_assoc_firstrow_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_firstrow_id);
  $last_id = $mysql_fetch_assoc_firstrow_id['id'];

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id FROM my_list ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 0,5